# How to include project references in .NET Interactive Notebooks?

Tags: c#, dotnet-interactive, .net-interactive, polyglot-notebooks

Using NET 6 I have the following project structure:

```
nuget.config
project.code-workspace
- Core
  Core.csproj
- Api
  Api.csproj
- Sim
  notebook.ipynb
```

Where `notebook.ipynb` is for now just:

```
#i "nuget:https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"

#r "nuget:Microsoft.Data.Analysis,0.*"

using System;
using Microsoft.Data.Analysis;

Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

How to include a project reference to Core and Api projects in `notebook.ipynb`?

I need to use some of the Core and Api project classes in `notebook.ipynb`.

Answer (score 7):

Currently that is not supported out of the box. See [this](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/issues/890) issue. I've tried to use `dotnet pack` and install created package from local folder but failed. The only I've managed to make work is to build solution and add .dll manually:

Assuming next solution structure:

```
connect_solution.ipynb
- ClassLib\ClassLib.csproj (contains SomeDep.cs)
- Api\Api.csproj (references ClassLib.csproj, contains WeatherForecast)
```

```
#!pwsh 
dotnet build .\Api\Api.csproj --verbosity quiet
```

```cs
#r ".\Api\bin\Debug\net6.0\Api.dll"
using ClassLib;
using Api;
new SomeDep().Display();
new WeatherForecast()
```